# How to get the Hadoop path with Java/Scala API in Code Repositories

Tags: apache-spark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

My need is to read other formats: JSON, binary, XML and infer the schema dynamically  within a transform in Code Repositories and using Spark datasource api.

Example:

```
val df = spark.read.json(<hadoop_path>)
```

For that, I need an accessor to the Foundry file system path, which is something like:

> foundry://...@url:port/datasets/ri.foundry.main.dataset.../views/ri.foundry.main.transaction.../startTransactionRid/ri.foundry.main.transaction...

This is possible with PySpark API (Python):

```
filesystem = input_transform.filesystem()
hadoop_path = filesystem.hadoop_path
```

However, for Java/Scala I didn’t find a way to do it properly.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L402 ?

Comment: Yes, I managed to read the files as dataset of String, and then json method to infer the Schema and it works.
For XML (with com.databricks.spark-xml library), it doesn't work as expected (maybe I need to add some options).
However, my need is more general and is how to get the hadoop path with Palantir Foundry API in JAVA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter to the Hadoop path has been recently added to Foundry Java API. By upgrading the version of the java transform (transformsJavaVersion >= 1.188.0), and you can get it:

```
val hadoopPath = myInput.asFiles().getFileSystem().hadoopPath()
```